# Tab stop does not work for text box control templates when windows theme is classic - What can I do?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, themes, controltemplate

When having, let's say, a `TextBox` and a `Button` like below, everything's fine. You can use tab stop to go back and forth between both controls.

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox>Type Here</TextBox>
  <Button>Click Me</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

But if you redefine the `TextBox` layout you cannot use tab stop to navigate to the button.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
          <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
          <Button>Template-Button</Button>
        </StackPanel>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

That is, you can still navigate back and forth between the text area and the 'Click Me'-button (which is still a separate control) but you won't reach the 'Template-Button' (which is part of the `TextBox`):

[image]

This issue does not occur with Windows 7 Basic style.

It seems that this is true for templating `TextBox`, but not necessarily to any controls. When templating a `Button` you can reach any parts of the control. In the following example you can reach the `ComboBox` as well as the `TextBox`.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
          <ComboBox>ComboBox</ComboBox>
          <TextBox>TextBox</TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
      </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
 </Style>
```

I wonder why it's like that and if there's any workaround other than not using `ControlTemplate` and 'misuse' of another control (like `Button`) as I lose `TextBox`-features and have to re-implement them.

Unfortunately, I didn't find anything when searching the Internet. I found some sources stating that the Windows classic templates are differently implemented than the respective Aero templates (for instance the [padding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9745086/779395)) but I'm not sure if this applies to tab stop as well (though there's a property `IsTabStop` - at least, I wasn't able to fix this issue by explicitly setting this property to `True`).

So, anything I can do?

---

Some additional notes:

- It's even worse for a PasswordBox as you cannot reach any templated elements for both Windows 7 classic and basic theme.
- This issue is reproducible on a Windows 7 system but AFAIK it also appears on Windows 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question right here on another question [Tab stop not working for textboxes inside data template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1972792/779395).

I didn't find it in the first place as I focused my search on windows 7 classic style.

So, all I need to do to fix this issue is to add a setter to my style which sets the `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation` value to `Continue`.

```
<Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="Continue" />
```

Due to this value each element gets keyboard focus:

> Continue: Each element receives keyboard focus, as long as it is a navigation stop. Navigation leaves the containing element when an edge is reached.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.tabnavigation.aspx) the default value is `Continue` but this is not true for the classic theme where the default value actually is `None`. Unfortunately, there's no hint anywhere.

Comment: Thanks...it was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `Control.IsTabStop` property on your `TextBox` to `True`? Please take a look at the [Control.IsTabStop Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.istabstop.aspx) page at MSDN for more information.

```
<TextBox IsTabStop="True" ... />
```

Comment: "though there's a property IsTabStop - at least, I wasn't able to fix this issue by explicitly setting this property to True" - by which I mean that I tried anything